# How can i estimate the pixel coordinates?

Tags: opencv, kalman-filter

I have a project that I need to follow the points like in the picture. I made a picture like this as a representation. I get the coordinates of the red dots as pixel coordinates once per second. Is there a way I can predict the green dots when I don’t take measurements afterwards? When I use the 2d-kalman filter (x,y,x’,y’ states) it keeps guessing in the direction of the blue arrow. I want to make correct predictions on the green dots, not this way. How can I do that.!

Thanks.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsB7E.png)

Comment: same question: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-can-i-estimate-the-pixel-coordinates/5499

Comment: For this problem, the only way to solve is to know the shape of the curve. No reasonable technique for estimation or extrapolation is likely to abruptly change direction (e.g. point 5 to point 6).

Comment: @bfris is exaggerating. you only need more history (use 3 points instead of 2 for a quadratic/parabolic fit) or more state (in the kalman filter).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, you're absolutely right. I was wrong. I had the idea you needed the inflection point to accurately get the curve. So I did an experiment in a Spreadsheet and did a second order polynomial trend line fit. Lo and behold, with just three points, you get a pretty good fit.